# Дважды просит пароль в админке opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Чтобы зайти в админку опенкарта нужно дважды ввести логин и пароль, первый раз страница просто перезагружается, а второй раз уже заходит в админку. При этом в следующий раз заходит с первого раза, но если очищаю все куки - снова со второго. Если я правильно понял то нужно смотреть в файл admin/controller/common/login.php но я там не нашел никаких отличий от такого же файла с другого сайта.
При перезагрузке страницы в тайтле появляется надпись Browser Check Page, может это в хостинге какая-то защита от ботов (так я прочитал в гугле).

Comment: Откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере на вкладе сеть и посмотрите в ответах сервера с какими параметрами куки устанавливаются при первой и второй попытках.

Comment: @Visman первый раз только 2 кукиса (PHPSESSION и currency), а после второго появляется 3-й кукис (CHECK), может это и есть кукис, который подсовывает хостинг, типо для защиты от ботов?

Comment: Пишите хостеру, чтобы снял защиту со всего сайта или с админки хотя бы. Если вы у него такую защиту не просили, то зачем она вам нужна!

Comment: @Visman, хорошо, спасибо, скорее всего она автоматически устанавливается, но я узнаю.